# Generating a range of characters

Tags: ruby, refactoring

Is there a more elegant way to refactor this? Perhaps, something shorter? My goal was to generate a string of all characters that could be used as delimiters.

```
supported_delimiters = ((33..46).map(&:chr) << (58..64).map(&:chr)).join
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do as below :

```
a = [*(33..46),*(58..64)].map(&:chr).join
a # => "!\"\#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@"
```

Comment: I knew there was a way, could you explain the ``*`` what's going on there?

Comment: @TheGrayFox `*` is a splat operator.. It is splatting the range into an array elements...